# TypeScript Compile Error- Could not select overload for 'call' expression- RegExp.test

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is wierd error I am getting while compiling small Regexp matching code-

Code -

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
response($.grep(modelState.Options, function (item) {
    return regExp.test(item);
}));
```

When I see the typescript definition of this "interface RegExp"

I can see the the test method there-

```
test(string: string): boolean;
```

Can anyone suggest me the resolution of this error-
"TypeScript Compile Error- Could not select overload for 'call' expression"

Comment: The compiler cannot guess the type of item ? Replace `function(item)` with `(item: string) =>`

Comment: Yeah fixed it with -   var str = item + "";
                    return regExp.test(str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this simplified example on the TypeScript Playground:

```
function example(item) {
    var regExp = /[0-9]/;
    return regExp.test(item);
}
```

Because `item` cannot be inferred, it has the `any` type. The Playground has no problem accepting an argument of type `any` to the regular expression test method.

This means you *could* call the `example` function with the following:

```
example({ this: 'works'});
```

It makes little sense to allow calls with literally any type, so by annotating the parameter you can prevent this kind of accident:

```
function example(item: string) {
    var regExp = /[0-9]/;
    return regExp.test(item);
}
```

The previous call that passed an object will now be highlighted as incorrect.